# How do I restrict the number of character of data before inserting it to the a table?

Tags: c#

I want to restrict the number of character before inserting it to the table. For example, I retrieved the value of the column "Address" whose data length is of 44 characters. But when I need to insert this value to another table, I want to restrict only 40 characters in the column "Address2" of another table as its data type is of 40 in length. Please help

Comment: What do you want to do with excess characters?

Comment: You do use ADO.NET, don't you ?

Comment: you may want to look at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-(data)/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

Comment: lots of answers below talking about text boxes and UI elements, which is fair enough in one sense: if your dataflow allows only 40 chars it doesn't make sense to accept 44 in the first place. However, if you need to truncate data, do so in a way that makes it clear it's been truncated - e.g. make the last char ">" or some such convention. At least then it's possible to see there is data missing. Ideally, though, revise the whole path to accept the same length data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
If (sAddress != null && sAddress.Length > 40) {
    sAddress = sAddress.SubString(0, 40)
}
```

Comment: I would suggest also checking for null before trying that.

Answer (score 1):

Put some validation on text box which is present on your form/page to accept only 40 characters . You can use following regular expression which will validate the input text for max 40 characters -

```
^.{1,40}$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the strings length simply and make some action if it is greater that the allowed length.

For example, You can truncate the string with a function like this:

```
string truncate(string s, int length)
{        
 return ( s.Length > length ) ?  s.Substring(0, length) : s;
}
```

so `truncate(Address,40)` will give You a shorter string and You can use it every time with this short form with any length.

Answer (score 0):

```
string YourVar = YourTextBox.text;
string VarToInsert = YourVar.Substring(0,40);
```

Answer (score 0):

For MVVM in WPF you can use [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)

```
    [Range(1,40)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name"));
        }
    }
```

XAML

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
```